# Find $f$, when $f(1)=f(2)=1$ and $f'(x)\leq (x^2-x-1) e^x, \forall x\in [1,2]$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f:[1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that
>   $f(1)=f(2)=1$ and $f'(x)\leq (x^2-x-1) e^x, \forall x\in [1,2]$. Find
>   $f(x)$.

I am pretty sure that from things I have tried with MVT the answer should be $f(x)=1+(x-1)(x-2)e^x, \forall x\in [1, 2]$, but I have no idea how to prove that. Any hint?

Comment: $g(x) = f(x) - (x-1)(x-2)e^x $ is decreasing and satisfies $g(1) = g(2)$. What can you conclude?

Comment: @SangchulLee How can it be proven that if a function is decreasing and has two equal values, then it is constant?

Comment: If $g(c) < g(a)$ for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$, then we must have $g(b) \leq g(c) < g(a)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $g(x):=(x^2-x-1)e^x-f'(x)\ge0$ on $[1,2]$, we have that $\int_1^2g(x)\,dx\ge0$.

Carrying out this integration explicitly and noting that $f(1)=f(2)$, we see that this integral is actually equal to $0$, whence $g(x)=0$ (integral of a positive continuous function is $0 \implies$ the function is $0$).

We thus see that $(x^2-x-1)e^x-f'(x)=0$, whence integrating tells us that $f(x)=1+(x-1)(x-2)e^x$ as you posit.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Carrying out this integration explicitly"?

Comment: @Jason Integrating $g(x)$ from $1$ to $2$ - the $(x^2-x-1)e^x$ contributes a $0$, and the $-f'(x)$ contributes a $f(1)-f(2)=0$

Comment: And may I ask a trivial question: (we haven't been taught that) How can I prove that if the integral of a positive continuous function is 0 means that the function is 0?

Comment: @Jason If $f(a)\neq0$, then for some $\delta >0$, $f(x)>\frac{f(a)}{2}$ on $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ by continuity, so the integral is $\ge \delta f(a)>0$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(x)\le (x^2-x-1)e^x$ we have that

$$f(x)-1=f(x)-f(1)=\int_1^x f'(t)dt\le \int_1^x (t^2-t-1)e^tdt=(x^2-3x+2)e^x.$$ In particular, for $x=2$ we have

$$0=1-1=f(2)-1\le (2^2-3\cdot 2+2)e^2=0.$$ So, actually we have $f'(x)=(x^2-x-1)e^x$ and $f(x)=(x^2-3x+2)e^x+1.$

By contrapositive, assume that there exist $x_0$ with $f'(x_0)< (x_0^2-x_0-1)e^{x_0}.$ Then, integrating as above, one has that for $x<x_0$ $$f(x)-1=f(x)-f(1)=\int_1^x f'(t)dt< \int_1^x (t^2-t-1)e^tdt=(x^2-3x+2)e^x.$$ This implies $f(2)<1$ which contradicts that $f(2)=1.$

Comment: Why do we "actually" have that? Proof?